# Определить когда ошибка, когда успешно, код оибки

Tags: javascript, xhr

```
xhr.onerror = xhr.onload = (t, id)  => {
    console.log(t.type);
    console.log(id);
}
```

Не понимаю, ответ сервера 500, а у меня по прежнему срабатывает слушатель load. По идеи должен сработать error.

Собственно вопрос в том, как получить код ошибки когда при загрузке файла на сервер. У клиента пропадает интернет?
Как узнать, что файл был успешно загружен на сервер?
Как получить код статуса загрузки, что за код отдает страница?

Comment: Попробуйте для `xhr.onerror` назначить отдельную функцию

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/error_event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ты используешь одну и ту же функцию на оба "события"...
Делай их две

```
xhr.onerror = (t, id)  => {
    console.log('Ошибка');
    console.log(t.type);
    console.log(id);
}
 
xhr.onload = (t, id)  => {
    console.log('Все хорошо');
    console.log(t.type);
    console.log(id);
}
```